# How to submit a form using a function? React Native

Tags: forms, react-native, react-hook-form, debouncing

I want to submit a form when I stop type, I'm using react hook form and call the handleSubmit in a function and it doesn't work, please help me, this is my code, I'm doing a map of this code, I've tried with ref but it doesn't work. This is my component.

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import tailwind from 'tailwind-rn';
import {useDebounce} from 'use-debounce';
import {useForm, Controller} from 'react-hook-form';
import {MAIN_COLOR, GRAY} from '../../constants/theme';

function RegisterFormHook({data, onSubmit, control, errors}) {
  const [underlineColor, setUnderlineColor] = React.useState(GRAY);
  const [field, setField] = React.useState('');
  const [value] = useDebounce(field, 1000);
  const inputElement = useRef();

  const {handleSubmit} = useForm();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (value.length !== 0) {
      handleSubmit(onSubmit({[data.name]: value}));
    }
    console.log(errors);
  }, [value]);

  const onFocus = () => {
    setUnderlineColor(MAIN_COLOR);
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    setUnderlineColor(GRAY);
  };

  return (
    <View style={tailwind('px-8')}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name={data.name}
        rules={data.rules}
        render={({field: {onChange, value}}) => (
          <TextInput
            placeholder={data.placeholder}
            ref={inputElement}
            style={[
              tailwind('text-black p-0 text-xl pb-1 flex-row'),
              {
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderBottomColor: underlineColor,
              },
            ]}
            onChangeText={value => {
              onChange(value);
              setField(value);
            }}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            value={value}
            onFocus={() => onFocus()}
          />
        )}
      />
      <Text>{errors[data.name]?.message}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default RegisterFormHook;
```

I want to submit in the useEffect but it just works when I press a button.

Comment: You want to submit the entered text, when you the user stops typing for e.g. 3 seconds. Without leaving textinput focus or press enter or close softwarekeyboard?

Comment: yeah, without leaving textinput focus, just when the user stop typing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/submit-after-idle-in-textfield) how you could implement scheduled action after input has been completed:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  let timer = React.useRef();
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (text) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        Alert.alert('TEXT : ' + text);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Card>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={'Enter the tetxt'}
          onChange={(e) => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            setText(e.nativeEvent.text);
          }}
        />
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: The component that I provided in the example can do that, but I can't call the handleSubmit of react hook form, has to be in a button but I need it in the useEffect state, I can't find any solution :/

Comment: Tried but cannot reproduce this issue, can you checkout  https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/0be0de ?

Comment: I will try, thanks buddy